# Probability that last two draws of integer product will be odd.

Tags: probability

An urn contains 6 balls, each labeled differently with one of the numbers from 1 to 6. Three balls are extracted without replacement.

a. What is the probability that the absolute value of the difference between the first number extracted and the second is greater or equal than 4?

b. What is the probability that the product of the second number extracted and the third is an odd number?

Comment: With such a small collection you can just do it case by case. Form part a:  Suppose the first draw is $1$...then you need the second to be $5,6$.  Now suppose the first draw is $2$...then you need the second to be $6$.  And so on.

Comment: I understand that there are 6 possible ways to have an absolute value greater or equal than 4: (6, 1), (1, 6), (6, 2), (2, 6), (5, 1), (1, 5). However, I'm not sure how to proceed from there ...

Comment: Ok, and how many possible ways can you draw the first two numbers?

Comment: I think that would be 6!/(6-2)!=30, implying that the odds are 6/30?

Comment: Correct. Well, a technical point:  $\frac 6{30}=\frac 15$ is the probability.  The "odds" are not written the same way.  Here the odds would be $6:24$ as there are $6$ winning outcomes and $24$ losing outcomes.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the question b., my logic goes: I have a 1/2 chance that my first draw will be an odd number, which gives me a 2/5 chance to draw an odd number on my second draw, and a 1/4 chance to draw an odd number on the third draw. Similarly, I have a 1/2 chance to draw an even number on my first draw, giving me a 3/5 chance to draw odd on my second draw, and 2/4 to draw an odd number on my third draw. So the total chance of the product of my last two draws being odd is: (1/2)*(3/5)*(2/4)+(1/2)*(2/5)*(1/4)=0.2.Is that correct?

Comment: Seems overly complicated.  There are $\binom 32=3$ ways to choose a pair of odd numbers from $\{1,\cdots, 6\}$.  There are $\binom 62=15$ ways to choose a a pair of numbers from the list.  Thus the probability is $\frac 3{15}=\frac 1{5}$.

Comment: Your calculation is fine, but needlessly complex.  You can ignore the first draw completely.  Choosing the second and third draws is just the same as drawing a pair.

Comment: Thank you very much, lulu!